# Authentication in client-server via a URL with JSON response

Tags: php, web-services, authentication

I wish to implement a two-way communication channel between a client and a server, over `HTTPS`. The client communicates via URLs, such as `http://example.com/method/param1/param2` and the server responds via `JSON`.

I wish to implement this in `PHP`. however, I am not sure how to do this with authentication.

I could simply authenticate the user with a login and password, and send a key back. The user could use this temporary key to communicate. The key expires after a certain period. However, I would like to know if this is the industry standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no exist a standard but the OWASP propose a session-based authentication. You send a token to the user when the user authenticate why user and password or apikey and the token allow user use the API, note: user password and apikey can't show in the URL.

Reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet

> Authentication and session management
>
> RESTful web services should use session-based authentication, either
>   by establishing a session token via a POST or by using an API key as a
>   POST body argument or as a cookie. Usernames, passwords, session
>   tokens, and API keys should not appear in the URL, as this can be
>   captured in web server logs, which makes them intrinsically valuable.
>
> OK:
>   https://example.com/resourceCollection//actionhttps://twitter.com/vanderaj/lists
>
> NOT OK:
>   https://example.com/controller//action?apiKey=a53f435643de32 (API
>   Key in
>   URL)http://example.com/controller//action?apiKey=a53f435643de32 
>   (transaction not protected by TLS; API Key in URL)